# Cases environment, actions on equations symbol

Tags: equations, typography, cases

Here is a typical case environment :

```latex
\begin{cases}
    8x+14y-76=0\\
    7x-4y+16=0
\end{cases}
```

It looks like this :
[image: First case example without the times 2 and times 7]

But I would like to put times 2 and times 7 seven before the first curly bracket like so :
[image]

For the moment I couldn't do better than that (the last image was modified with gimp) :

```latex
\begin{cases}
    8x+14y-76=0     &       \times 2\\
    7x-4y+16=0      &       \times 7
\end{cases}
```

Which gives this :
[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Answer (score 2):

Like this?

[image]

With `array`:

```
\documentclass{article}


\begin{document}
\[\setlength\arraycolsep{1pt}
\begin{array}{r}
    \times 2    \\  \times 7\\
\end{array}\left\{\begin{array}{l}
                    8x+14y-76=0\\
                    7x-4y+16=0
                   \end{array}\right.
\]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

I propose this other layout, with the `systeme` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{systeme}

\begin{document}

\[ \systeme{%
    8x+14y-76=0@\mathsf{{}\times 2},
    7x-4y+16=0@\mathsf{{}\times 7}
}\]

\end{document}
```

[image]